# Stop / Kill a Python script using cron

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron

My goal is to run my python script each day (besides Friday and Saturday) at 10:00 and terminate it by 18:00.

I added the following to the crontab but the second command isn't working.

```
0 10 * * 0,1,2,3,4 /home/pi/MotionDetector.py
0 18 * * 0,1,2,3,4 /home/pi/MotionDetector.py killall -9 MotionDetector.py
```

Using Linux 2.7.9

I tried [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/797057/how-to-kill-all-python-processes-except-one-from-bash) solution that worked Via the terminal but not in cron (when I typed the command in the terminal it closed the script right away but when I put it on the crontab it didn't do anything)

Comment: Why are you passing `killall` as an argument to `MotionDetector.py` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For killing the job:

```
0 18 * * 0,1,2,3,4 /usr/bin/pkill -f MotionDetector.py
```

`pkill` kills a process by name. While the default search criteria is to find the process by its full name, `-f` argument allows you to search by any of the parts in the process name.

---

**Updated solution to account for the scenario raised by [@håken-lid](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1977847/h%C3%A5ken-lid):**

When the script is executed by cron or by the user, the process name would be in the format:
*cron*: `/home/pi/venv/bin/python /home/pi/MotionDetector.py`
*user*: `python MotionDetectory.py`

Using simple regex patterns we can kill the process started by,

- cron or user:

  `0 18 * * 0,1,2,3,4 /usr/bin/pkill -f 'python.*MotionDetector.py'`
- only cron

  `0 18 * * 0,1,2,3,4 /usr/bin/pkill -f ^'/home/pi/venv/bin/python /home/pi/MotionDetector.py'`

Comment: Why use `-f` here? Wouldn't you risk killing for example `vim MotionDetector.py`?